# Eloquent Javascript Squirrel + Pizza Correlation code

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Im struggling to understand what the computer is "thinking" when you tell it this "for in" loop:

```
var map = {pizza: 0.069, touched tree: -0.081};
for (var event in map) console.log(map[event]);
```

Comment: for each property of the Object `map` log the value of the property?

Comment: though, of course, your declaration of `map` is invalid, therefore the for loop wont run

Comment: Which part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: i think what is confusing me is that "event" is not even in the var map, so i struggle to understand how the computer knows what i want to do here (it obviously knows because it spits out what i want)

What might help me understand is seeing some other applications of the for(x in y) format